# Legacy ActiveX Control with .NET 4.0 - Microsoft POS

Tags: asp.net, .net, activex, point-of-sale

We have an ActiveX Control calling [Microsoft Point of Sale for .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5355).  However POS doesn't work with .NET 4.0 due to CAS (Code Access Security) which is obsolete for .NET 4.0.

The best resource I've found is on this [LavaBlast Blog](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/06/06/Using-Microsoft-POS-for-NET-in-2011.aspx), however I've been unable to get it to work.

At what point should I be setting this?  I didn't think ActiveX controls had configuration files associated with them for this setting, and wouldn't this be a setting on the user's computer and not on a webserver's web.config file?

Here is the code and the specific error:

```
PosExplorer explorer = new PosExplorer();
```

> This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by
>   the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility
>   reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration
>   switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570

Comment: Why can't you just target .NET 3.5 and install that on your POS hardware?

Comment: Users are being upgraded to .NET 4.0 by their companies, so we have no control over what version of .NET they're running.